# JavaFX TableView - adding a row

Tags: javafx, tableview

I have an application that has a tableview in it.

I get information from my database and display the data.

Is there a way to have the bottom row in the tableview as a way of entering new data?

I have seen online having texfields and an add button but I was wondering if I can enter new data straight from the tableview.

Thank you for any help or advice

Answer (score 0):

You can provide this behavior by extending TableCell in your own custom class. You then set the columns their CellFactory to this type of cell where you provide a custom implementation. Then you add your own implementation of how to show a textfield in a cell when someone clicks on it. Lastly you'll need to add an empty row to the tableview.

I've got some example code for a TreeTableCell which is a lot like a TableCell.
You can use this as an example to write your own custom TableCell.

**Custom cell**
        package be.vincentnagy.ehka.treetableview.cell;

```
import be.vincentnagy.ehka.activity.Activity;
import be.vincentnagy.ehka.category.Category;
import be.vincentnagy.ehka.treetableview.item.CustomTreeItem;
import be.vincentnagy.ehka.treetableview.item.TotalTreeItem;
import javafx.geometry.Pos;
import javafx.scene.control.TextField;
import javafx.scene.control.TreeItem;
import javafx.scene.control.TreeTableCell;
import javafx.scene.input.KeyCode;

import java.text.NumberFormat;
import java.text.ParseException;
import java.time.Month;
import java.time.Year;

/**
 * @author Vincent Nagy
 * A MoneyFormatCell is a custom implementation of a TreeTableCell.
 * It provides editing functionality for specific cells
 * and propagates changes to the underlying data items.
 */
public class MoneyFormatCell extends TreeTableCell<CustomTreeItem,Number>{
    private TextField textField;
    private static final NumberFormat NUMBER_FORMAT = NumberFormat.getNumberInstance();
    private static final NumberFormat CURRENCY_FORMAT = NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance();

    static {
        NUMBER_FORMAT.setMaximumFractionDigits(2);
        NUMBER_FORMAT.setMinimumFractionDigits(2);
    }
    public MoneyFormatCell() {

    }

    /**
     * updateItem gets called whenever a MoneyFormatCell changes state.
     * Editing gets disabled for TotalTreeItem and CategoryTreeItem.
     * Provides the TextBox inside the cell for input.
     * @param item Item being added to the MoneyFormatCell. Only gets called at initial filling of the Table
     * @param empty  Whether or not the cell is empty
     */
    @Override
    protected void updateItem(Number item, boolean empty) {
        super.updateItem(item, empty);
        setAlignment(Pos.CENTER_RIGHT);

        TreeItem<CustomTreeItem> treeItem = getTreeTableRow().getTreeItem();

        //Set editable if it's a leaf(aka if it's an ActivityDataItem
        setEditable(treeItem != null && treeItem.isLeaf());
        //Set editable if it's not the the Totals row and not a Category row
        setEditable(!(treeItem != null && (treeItem.getValue() instanceof TotalTreeItem || treeItem.getValue() instanceof Category)));

        if(empty){
            setText(null);
            setGraphic(null);
        }else {
            if( isEditing()){
                if(textField != null){
                    textField.setText(getString());
                    setText(null);
                    setGraphic(textField);
                }
            } else {
                if(item == null){
                    if(textField != null && !textField.getText().equals("")){
                        stoppedEditing();
                    }
                    setText("");
                }else{
                    setText(NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance().format(item.doubleValue()));
                }
                setGraphic(null);
            }
        }
    }

    /**
     * startEdit gets called whenever a MoneyFormatCell moves into editing mode.
     * It creates the TextField element if it isn't already created
     * and switches the graphics from string to the TextField.
     */
    @Override
    public void startEdit() {
        if(isEditable()) {
            super.startEdit();
            if (textField == null) {
                createTextField();
            }

            setText(null);
            setGraphic(textField);
            textField.requestFocus();
            textField.selectAll();
        }
    }

    /**
     * createTextField creates a TextField to allow editing of data in the Cell.
     * It initializes the event handlers for the Escape key and the Enter key.
     * It also listens for when it gets unfocused.
     */
    private void createTextField() {
        textField = new TextField(getString());
        textField.setMinWidth(this.getWidth() - this.getGraphicTextGap()* 2);

        textField.setOnKeyReleased(event -> {
            if (event.getCode() == KeyCode.ESCAPE){
                cancelEdit();
            } else if(event.getCode() == KeyCode.ENTER){
                stoppedEditing();
            }
        });
        textField.focusedProperty().addListener((observable, oldValue, newValue) -> {
            if(oldValue){
                stoppedEditing();
            }
        });

    }

    /**
     * stoppedEditing gets called whenever a cell leaves editing mode.
     * This happens whenever the Enter key gets pressed or when the focus shifts away from the cell.
     * If there is no value, it will simple cancel out.
     * Otherwise it will propagate the changes to the respective ActivityTreeItem
     * and commit the edit to the cell.
     */
    private void stoppedEditing(){
        try {
            if (textField.getText().equals("")) {
                cancelEdit();
            } else {
                if (getTreeTableRow().getTreeItem().getValue() instanceof Activity) {
                    Activity activityTreeItem = (Activity) getTreeTableRow().getTreeItem().getValue();

                    activityTreeItem.setActivityDataForDate(Month.valueOf(getTableColumn().getText()).getValue(),
                            Year.parse(getTableColumn().getParentColumn().getText()).getValue(),
                            NUMBER_FORMAT.parse(textField.getText()).doubleValue());
                }
                commitEdit(NUMBER_FORMAT.parse(textField.getText()).doubleValue());
            }
        } catch (ParseException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }


    /**
     * cancelEdit gets called when the cell stops editing and
     * either was left by using the Escape key or there was no new value in the cell
     */
    @Override
    public void cancelEdit() {
        super.cancelEdit();

        setText(getFormatted());
        setGraphic(null);
    }

    /*
        format into double number for editing in text field
     */
    private String getString() {
        //return getItem() == null ? "" : NumberFormat.getNumberInstance().format(((double)getItem()));
        return getItem() == null ? "" : NUMBER_FORMAT.format(((double)getItem()));
    }

    /*
        format into double number with currency locale
     */
    private String getFormatted(){
        return getItem() == null ? "" :CURRENCY_FORMAT.format(getItem().doubleValue());
    }

}
```

**Creating custom columns**

```
    /**
 * Create a column for the requested months in the specified year. Doesn't need to start at January.
 * Bind the cell to the ActivityTreeItem valueProperty
 *
 * @param yearColumn The column to initialize
 * @param year       The year it belongs to
 * @param startMonth The starting month in case it's not a full year
 * @param endMonth   The ending month in case it's not a full year
 */
private void createMonthColumns(TreeTableColumn<CustomTreeItem, Number> yearColumn, int year, int startMonth, int endMonth) {
    for (int i = startMonth; i <= endMonth; i++) {
        Month month = Month.of(i);
        TreeTableColumn<CustomTreeItem, Number> ttc = new TreeTableColumn<>(month.toString());
        ttc.setMinWidth(MIN_TABLE_WIDTH);

        Month currentMonth = Month.of(i);
        ttc.setCellValueFactory(param -> {
            if (param.getValue().getValue() instanceof Activity) {
                Activity treeItem = (Activity) param.getValue().getValue();
                return treeItem.getActivityDataForDate(currentMonth.getValue(), year);
            } else if (param.getValue().getValue() instanceof TotalTreeItem) {
                TotalTreeItem totalTreeItem = (TotalTreeItem) param.getValue().getValue();
                return totalTreeItem.valueProperty(currentMonth.getValue(), year);
            }
            return null;
        });

        ttc.setCellFactory(param -> new MoneyFormatCell());

        yearColumn.getColumns().add(ttc);
    }
}
```

Comment: hmm ... fine when it works for you. But note: basically it's wrong to change the data inside a cell: that's the task of a dedicated commitHandler (even though core fx has a similar  bug: https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8187473)

Comment: @kleopatra Thanks for mentioning this. I did not know about a commitHandler. I'll read up on this :)

Comment: @Vinagy You say "Lastly you'll need to add an empty row to the tableview." - how would I do this? This is the part I am struggling with now!

Comment: @amydowse Let's say you've got a TableView<Person> then you would add an empty person by adding a new person without any data to the ObservableList that is linked to your tableview. A good complete example of this can be found in the javadocs. https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/control/TableView.html

If you updated your question and added your code, it would be easier to point you in the right direction :)
Please also click on the up arrow on my answer if you appreciate my answer.